# "Row, row, row your boat" and Telemann's Concerto in B Flat TWV44:43

Tags: baroque-period

Does the same rhythm from "Row, row, row your boat" copy the ending of Telemann's Concerto?

It appears lots of music copied the style of the Baroque era.

Comment: I’m reading the score, you must be talking about the triplet arpeggio- merrily merrily merrily merrily?

Comment: Can you point us to a specific timepoint in a video to show us what section you're referencing?

Comment: @Richard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWhAwQgcjgg&t=433s

Comment: @RichardBarber yes.

Answer (score 2):

The same rhythm does appear, but only briefly. The relationship is a result of this rhythm and the fact that the Telemann uses the same or similar scale degrees as "Row." "Row" begins with repeated instances of scale-degree 1 (what we call the tonic of the key), and that's exactly what's repeated at the beginning of your [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWhAwQgcjgg&t=433s). And since "Row" is so culturally ingrained, it's easy to hear a passing connection when we hear the Telemann. The subsequent triplets, even though they're on different scale degrees in the Telemann, add to the the similarity.

It's a lot like how people often tend to hear "Jingle Bells" at the end of [Shostakovich's Fifth Symphony](https://youtu.be/YS4dcZ90fN0?t=2966). Even though the scale degree is wrong (it's 3 in "Jingle Bells" but 5 in the Shostakovich), the rhythm is so ingrained in our memories that we immediately make the connection.